# Last record in SQLite database doesn't get deleted

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite, sql-delete

I have a toggle button which saves data to SQLite table when checked and deletes data from table when unchecked. And I am populating a listview from the same table. So when I uncheck the toggle button, am able to delete the records one by one except the one last record, which shows up in listview.

But when I check the toggle button to insert new record, the one last record in listview is replace by new record.

Below is the toggle button code

```
if(bookmark.isChecked()){
                // Insert record
                }
        }else{
                dbAdapter.write();
                dbAdapter.deleteSingleBookmark(urlHost1);
                dbAdapter.close();
               }
```

Sqlite code

```
public boolean deleteSingleBookmark(String bookmarkHost2) throws SQLException{
    return (int) db.delete(BOOKMARKS_TABLE, BOOKMARK_NAME + "=?", new String[] { bookmarkHost2 }) > 0;
}
```

I tried ">=0" in deleteSingleBookmark method, but that doesn't work. My issue is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122099/sqlite-delete-last-row-refresh-not-working), but am not using cursor.

How do I delete this one last record from the listview?

Comment: What this function `deleteSingleBookmark` returns when you are trying to delete the last record?

Comment: try this, return (int) db.delete(BOOKMARKS_TABLE, BOOKMARK_NAME + "='"
    + bookmarkHost2 + "'", null) >

Comment: @SSS It returns a db record

Comment: @ImtiyazKhalani Your code crashes the app

Comment: @User210282 your db.delete() method will return the deleted row id if the row is deleted, otherwise it will return 0. So try to print the return value of db.delete() method to know whether it is deleted or not.

Comment: @ImtiyazKhalani I found a work around, actually the record was deleted, but the entry in the listview remained as it is even after using notifyDataSetChanged method. So now I just clear the list when listview item count = 1

Answer (score 1):

You need to operate with data in ListViewAdapter which you provided for your ListView.
Delete needed data from adapter and call method:

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public boolean deleteSingleBookmark(String bookmarkHost2) throws SQLException{
    return (int) db.delete(BOOKMARKS_TABLE, BOOKMARK_NAME + "="+bookmarkHost2, null) > 0;
}
```

Comment: Tried your code, but throws Unfortunately, App has stopped. In logcat, SQLiteException is thrown, with this line as the  cause.